# Google API refresh tokens not honoring 'incremental scope' request

Tags: google-api, google-authentication

We have a webapp that integrates with a number of Google APIs (calendars, contacts, drive). We have an integrations panel where the user can selectively check `on` each integration. When a new integration is enabled we save the new refresh token Google returns and flag the old one as `inactive`. Great so far.

The problem is when we request a new scope (incremental), Google seems to correctly add the scope to the User (if we check granted scopes from the frontend it shows the correct list), but if we check scopes from the access token it will only list profile and whatever we just requested.

So if someone enables Calendar, that refresh token will have 'profile' and 'calendar', but if they then enable Drive, the new refresh token will have only 'profile' and 'drive', not 'calendar'. This is especially problematic for our Drive worker, as it will generate a lovely slew of errors as it tries to build out a User's Drive with a valid refresh token but invalid scopes.

On the backend, I'm using the `setIncludeGrantedScopes(true)` method before I cash in the `code`, and as far as I know the front end is doing what it should (it does seem to have the expected scopes), but the refresh token is not inclusive.

Tips/tricks/gotchas/etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, it turns out that this was a fairly simple solution, but was documented in only one place: when the front-end requests an additional scope, it must *also* send up all current scopes.

Failing to do this will cause the returned refresh token to represent only the scopes included in the grant request, while the *app* will incrementally gain scopes as expected.